# Is it possible to send sms by GSM Modem in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need to use GSM Modem in my project in ASP.NET and i searched about it but i found many articles in Windows application not in ASP.NET, i want to know is there any way to send SMS by GSM Modem in ASP.NET?
Let me know if there is hope.

Comment: How do those articles do it?  Do you have an example?  What makes the code running on a web server different from code running in an application?  Did you *try*?

Comment: No i didn't, because they need to communicate with COM Ports and i thought in ASP.NET we can not make a connection to COM Ports.

Comment: It depends on the specifics of what you're trying to do.  Server-side code most certainly *can* connect with server-side COM Ports.  It can't connect with *client-side* COM Ports, for obvious reasons.  For that you would need client-side code (there would, of course, be restrictions on what can be done with untrusted in-browser code).  The question at the moment is pretty broad and vague.

Comment: You are right, i want to send SMS and receive, You know GSM Modem should connect to Server and i use Shared Servers that i don't access them, i want to know is it impossible or not?

Comment: Well, if you can't connect the modem to the server, then using it would seem problematic.  If you can connect the modem, it's possible.  If you can't, it's not.